# missing libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386, libc6:i386 how do install ubuntu 12.04

Tags: steam

Does anyone know how to install these packages for steam `libgl1-mesa-dri:i386`, `libgl1-mesa-glx:i386`, `libc6:i386` without it saying that it was unable to locate the packages?

Comment: i meant on steam

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-core` terminal command. And I will help you out.

Comment: I need to know which version of xorg is installed.

Comment: that does not work the same as sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-utopic:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386

Comment: Will you PLEASE post output of `dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-core` and I will help you. Or you do not need any help? It won't WORK. It will give information.

Comment: i don't know witch xorg is or were to find it

Comment: You do not need to know or find anything. Just run the given command in terminal, [edit] your question and post output there. After that I will give you a command to fix it.

Comment: there's nothing popping up

Comment: Do not re-type the command, but copy it and paste to terminal. And it is one command, not two.

Comment: all it does is say (precise)jacksepticeye@localhost:~$ like it all ways does

Comment: OK, paste the command there and press Enter.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing Wine - it resolved the issue for me ;-)

I usually install Wine before Steam and do not get the problem.
After recently completely zapping and reinstalling Ubuntu, I forgot to install Wine and got the same problem with Steam.  After installing Wine the problem disappeared.

Comment: Thank you. This got me over the hump OP was at but then it wouldn't start for a different reason. At that point I did an uninstall and reinstall and finally it worked.

Comment: Wait, I forgot to say that I'm running on Kali. I was trying to start steam by typing `steam` in the console. But that wasn't working. It does work if you run steam from the GUI though. In other words, type "steam" into application finder and open it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-lts-trusty libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty:i386
```

and reboot.

This will install graphical stack of 12.04.5. It should work.

It looks like you already removed xserver with some wrong commands.

And also try this

```
 sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
 sudo ppa-purge ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

Comment: does not work still

Comment: Does it install? What `dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-core` shows?

Comment: Did you install anything from xorg-edgers?

Comment: does not install and the dpkg command says dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-core
dpkg: warning: ignoring option --foreign-architecture=i386: this architecture cannot be foreign

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: it got done and said this Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-53-generic_3.13.0-53.89~precise1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) what do i do